# How to lock the screen from notification click in Android?

Tags: android-activity, push-notification, android-notifications

How to lock my screen by clicking on notification of my app?

```
 public void openNotification(View v) {
 //This is to notification
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Easy Lock")
            .addAction()
            //.setActions()
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentText("Press Here to Lock Your Screen")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Comment: Would you indicate how the code you have presented is related to your question? Does it try to solve the problem you are having but fails to do so? If so, can you give any detail about _how_ it fails, like any error logs it outputs?

Comment: This is an method which is to be called when a button clicked and this method is creating a notification successfully but i want an action to lock the Android screen when we hit the notification 
Thanks for the reply and sorry for delay @halfer

Comment: Righto. I have searched for this [using this query](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android+lock+screen+java) and can see two Stack Overflow links that seem to describe the feature you want. Are they any good? If not, perhaps you could outline how your question is different?

Comment: My question was different.
How to add an action to notification which locks the screen
Instead of pressing lock button.
Example of apps like 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.katecca.screenofflock
But this app locks the screen by widget.
My app should lock from notification click

Comment: I'm not an Android dev, but it seems there's two things here: (1) how to do something on a Notification click, and (2) how to lock the screen. Your code solves (1) and the links I have supplied solve (2). Doesn't that mean you just need to put the two together?

Comment: Ok i will try those
 thank you very much